# Using Samsung Focus (Windows Phone 7) Phone as Webcam for Windows 7 Computer

Tags: windows-7, streaming, webcam, windows-phone

I'm running Windows 7 x64 and I bought a Samsung Focus yesterday.

I'd really like to use its 5 megapixel camera as a webcam for myself, is there any software out there to do something like this for Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Sorry, Windows Phone 7 app makers: the camera's off-limits](http://tech.fortune.cnn.com/2010/10/22/sorry-windows-phone-7-app-makers-the-camera%E2%80%99s-off-limits/).

> Right now, developers for WP7 are at a
>   bit of a disadvantage when it comes to
>   accessing the phone's camera, a key
>   piece of hardware that can give apps a
>   big wow factor. Simply put, they can't
>   use it. Developers are usually
>   provided the necessary tools and
>   documentation for making software for
>   an OS in the form of an SDK, or
>   software development kit, but in this
>   case it appears that Microsoft left
>   out the software hooks necessary to
>   fully control the lens.

So it seems like the camera is unusable for video streaming application. You may have to wait for an update to the WP7 SDK that *may* enable free use of the camera. For the moment, as that article says, the camera can only be used by the Microsoft applications that come with the WP7.

Comment: That does not work with Windows Phone 7. Only Windows Mobile 6.5 or 6 or something.

Comment: You are right, so I rewrote my answer. Unfortunately, the answer is "no go". You need an Android phone or iPhone for that.

Comment: @Indebi: Thanks for accepting my (negative) answer. Just to remark that the bounty needs to be awarded separately.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that I assumed it did it automatically, the bountry has been awarded.